# Error: Route.put() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

My terminal console is giving me the following:

```
  Error: Route.put() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

This is my app > routes > articles.server.routes.js

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller'),
        articles = require('../../app/controllers/articles.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.route('/api/articles')
        .get(articles.list)
        .post(users.requiresLogin, articles.create);

    app.route('/api/articles/:articleId')
        .get(articles.read)
        // .put(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.update)
        // .delete(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.delete);
        app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);


};
```

I am getting error for the following:

```
// .put(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.update)
// .delete(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization,
```

When I comment these 2 lines out, the errors in the console go away.

I have  "method-override": "~2.2.0" in my `package.json` and it's properly installed. And I properly declared it in my `express.js` file so I'm unsure what I did wrong.

```
var config = require('./config'),
    express = require('express'),
    morgan = require('morgan'), 
    compress = require('compression'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),****
    session = require('express-session'),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(){
    var app = express();

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
        app.use(compress());
    }

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(methodOverride());
```

Comment: please show `articles.hasAuthorization` function

Comment: I got it. I put hasAuthorization in my user controller rather than my articles controller. Thanks 5 million for getting me to look in the right place!

Comment: @BenWong Can you post that as an answer, instead of a comment, and then mark it accepted?

Answer (score 2):

In my case this is what I did. Instead of importing my controller like this:

```js
const forgotPassword  = require('../controllers/forgotPasswordController');
```

I used this:

```js
const { forgotPassword } = require('../controllers/forgotPasswordController');
```

It solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the parameters in api function signature not applicable with the params it expected in compilation time. Make sure your controller imported correctly, and also your contriller action (the function) written in the same at api and cntroller (copy paste).

Answer (score -1):

In case others come across this: when this happened to me, I had mismatching calls, i.e. a `PUT` was calling a `POST`. Make sure everything lines up!